# Few panels within the sidebarPanel in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, sidebar

I am building my first app in `shiny`. The problem to solve is like this.
I've `ui`

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("My"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel("Variables",
      sliderInput("bins",
                  "Number of circles:",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 50,
                  value = 30),

      sliderInput("bins",
                  "Number of triangels:",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 50,
                  value = 1)
    ),


    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Data", plotOutput("distPlot")),
      tabPanel("Data1", textOutput("text1")),
      tabPanel("Data2", plotOutput("distPlot1")))

    )
  )
))
```

and `server`

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({

    # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
    x    <- faithful[, 2]
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

    # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')

  })

  output$distPlot1 <- renderPlot({
    x    <- faithful[, 2]
    plot(density(x))
  })

  output$text1 <- renderText({
    "Hello mother"
  })

})
```

The question concern `ui` part. I'd like to fave 2 panels in the `sidebarPanel` - triangles and circles, similar to that what is in the `mainPanel` i.e. `Data, Data1, Data2`.
Thanks for the comments!

Comment: Just add another `tabsetPanel` and some `tabPanels` inside your `sidebarPanel`. I don't see what else could be a problem.

Comment: thanks @K.Rohde, it works fine